# How can to click button when write log in form?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have 2 Form:

Form1: show Form 2 and write log on Form2

```
Public Class Form1

        Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
            Dim frm2 As New Form2
            frm2.Show()
            For i = 0 To 100000
                frm2.setLog(i.ToString)
            Next
        End Sub
    End Class
```

Form2:

```
 Public Class Form2
        Dim bLog As Boolean = True
        Public Sub setLog(ByVal msg As String)
            If bLog Then
                Label1.Text = msg
            End If
        End Sub

        Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
            bLog = False
        End Sub
    End Class
```

How can click button "Button2" on Form2?
Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#, call Application.DoEvents() in your setLog function.